# How do I make proxies work with requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

When I try to run my code, I get an error and I can't understand why. Help!

```
import requests
import json

proxies = {
  "https": "189.113.217.35:49733",
  "http": "5.252.161.48:8080"
}

r = requests.get("https://groups.roblox.com/v1/groups/1",proxies=proxies)
j = r.json()
print(j)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Alderven I figured it out, the ip adress didn't have access to the proxies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the ip adress didn't have access to the proxies.

Answer (score 0):

it pretty simple, i would create a session:

> session = requests.Session()

then a proxies dict:

> proxies = {
> 'http': 'http://5.252.161.48:8080',
> 'https': 'http://5.252.161.48:8080'
> }

and inject the proxies in the session

> session.proxies.update(proxies)